Where can i practice my ML concepts on instance based resources?
I have to appear for an MLE interview and i am well to do with all the key concepts and when i look for interview questions online all i get is questions directly asking the terms say What is bias variance tradeoff? . I am honestly sick of these questions and i want some type of questions that tingle my brain and force me to think of a solution. for example if i have a dataset of say 10000 dimensions and my machine capability is limited, what solutions i could think of?.
could you please suggest some resource from where i can get these types of questions?

You can find many such practical questions here, on DataScienceSE! :) Seriously, it's a good source of data science problems to practice your skills.

Indeed, there are some great questions here but then some of them require extensive digging into the dataset and all, i was looking for some structure source
